# variation of parameter, why no other solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider equation: $x'(t)=a(t)x(t)+f(t), x(t_0)=x_0$ and variation of parameter method.

Why this method works? Sure we get one solution, but how we know there are no more other solutions?

I think it might be because of Picard's Lindelof theorem but it only says something about local solutions. If it is the case why can we extend to global solutions?

Comment: If $x(t)$ is a solution and $y(t)$ is another solution with the same initial condition then define $u(t)=x(t)-y(t)$ and we see $u'(t) = a(t)u(t)$ and $u(t_0)=0$. Now $u(t)=0$ for all $t$ is a solution, and if that is the only one, it means $x(t)=y(t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: To show uniqueness of the above $u(t)$, generally we can write $u(t) = r(t) \exp(\int_0^t a(v)dv)$ for some function $r(t)$ with $r(t_0)=0$ (recall that $\exp(z)>0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$). Now $u'(t) = r'(t) \exp(\int_0^t a(v)dv) + a(t)u(t)= a(t)u(t)$ for all $t$ so $r'(t)=0$ for all $t$; since $r(t_0)=0$ it means $r(t)=0$ for all $t$.